# Search results from specific country in Bing Search API?

Tags: php, web-services, search-engine, bing, bing-api

I want to know is this possible in Bing search API to restrict results from a specific country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [See `location:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795647.aspx):

> Returns webpages from a specific country or region. Specify the
>   country or region code directly after the location: keyword. For
>   language codes, see Bing API Version 2 Documentation. To return
>   results for two or more languages, use OR to group the languages.